# Firestore Cloud functions use variable in property for update document

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to use a variable as property when updating a document via Cloud functions.
Maybe I miss the syntax here or is it simply not possible.

```
var value = 'myValue'
var name = 'myVariable'

admin.firestore().collection('mycollection').doc('mydocument').update({ name : value});
```

The document is updated but it shows then name = myValue and would like to see in the document myVariable = myValue.
What would be the syntax to achieve that to be flexible?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
var value = 'myValue'
var name = 'myVariable'

admin.firestore().collection('mycollection').doc('mydocument').update({ [name] : value})
```